Can't install Samsung Smart Switch
I want to install Samsung Smart Switch on my Samsung Galaxy M30S SM-M307FN. The requirements according to the Smart Switch website are

Which devices support Smart Switch?
Phone/Tablet: Android OS version 4.3 or later

But the install fails:
> adb install "Samsung Smart Switch Mobile_3.7.60.1.apk"
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install Samsung Smart Switch Mobile_3.7.60.1.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_BLOCKED_CROSS_DOWN: INSTALL_FAILED_BLOCKED_CROSS_DOWN]

Output from adb logcat -T 1
I AASA_ASKSManager:  advanced hash::0c7f814f2dd994ce55e16dd062472d14a57ade935f12cb075e349e526ee13ff2
I AASA_ASKSManager:  AASA_VerifyToken START
I AASA_ASKSManager: index : 1.1
D AASA_ASKSManager: mTokenName : SEC-INF/buildinfo.xml SignerVersion : 
I AASA_ASKSManager: signerCert is verificated!
I AASA_ASKSManager: CAcert is verificated!
I AASA_ASKSManager: rootCert is verificated!
I AASA_ASKSManager: OK:com.sec.android.easyMover
I AASA_ASKSManager: OK:HASH
I AASA_ASKSManager: FAILED CROSSDOWN for sep lite
E AASA_ASKSManager:  com.sec.android.easyMover, returnValue : -3006
W PackageManager: INSTALL_FAILED_BLOCKED_CROSS_DOWN
D PackageManager: result of install: -3006{107580853}

It seems the Samsung Device Protection Manager blocks the installation with FAILED CROSSDOWN for sep lite. What does that mean?

The compability section in the playstore says Android 5.0 and up required, but the device is on Android 11. Also it says Compability: Won't work on your device. Why is that?

As the phone is a Samsung phone Galaxy Store should be installed. I would try to download/install/update Smart Switch from there. May be the release in Galaxy Store and Google Play use different signatures or have other differences.

I just checked the Play Store link from my Samsung Galaxy M12 and got the same issue, However, on the top of "About this app", it's written "If you can't download, you can open Smart Switch from device's Settings menu". Searching for "smart switch" inside the Settings app returned "Bring data from old device" in "Accounts and backup" menu. I think recent Samsung devices have this app integrated in the system.

It turns out there's a 'Smart Switch Agent' app preinstalled at /system/app/SmartSwitchAgent/SmartSwitchAgent.apk with application ID com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent You can interact with it through Settings > Accounts and backup > Smart Switch. When you hit Bring data from old device or External storage transfer there, it will prompt for installation of SmartSwitch and download and install it, if not already installed, and launch the app.

Download Smart Switch?
Smart Switch brings your data from your old device to your new phone.
View app details for Smart Switch

Afterwards the Play Store says

This app is no longer compatible With your device. Contact the developers for more info.
The app installed on your device didn't come from Google Play and may have a different app experience. You can update the app from the original source or re-install from Google Play.


I adb pulled the apk and tried to adb install it but got the same error. The signer of the downloaded one is CN=Samsung Platform Key for non-Galaxy devices, OU=Mobile Communications Business, O=Samsung Electronics Co. Ltd., L=Suwon City, ST=Republic of Korea, C=KR whereas the one from the Play Store is EMAILADDRESS=android.os@samsung.com, CN=Samsung Cert, OU=DMC, O=Samsung Corporation, L=Suwon City, ST=South Korea, C=KR. You can generate a download link at vas.samsungapps.com (via)
For reference, the log of the successful installation:
D Settings: Package not found : com.sec.android.easyMover
D SamsungExternalStoragePreferenceController: easyMover resolveActivity is not null, start easyMover Agent, uri : Intent { act=com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent.action.AUTO_DOWNLOAD cmp=com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent/.ServiceActivity }
I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent.action.AUTO_DOWNLOAD cmp=com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent/.ServiceActivity} from uid 1000
D MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent, userId = 0
D PkgDataHelper: notifyAppCreate(), pkgName: com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent, sendRet: true
D MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent, userId = 0
V ActivityManager: Changed top to 10149,ProcessRecord{85aa6cc 29981:com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent/u0a149}
W PkgPredictorService: background app without no launcher icon com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent for.uid: 10149 userId: 0
D SehCodecSolutionService: Update top [com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent]
I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent.action.START_FROM_SETTINGS flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent/.DialogActivity} from uid 10149
D MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent, userId = 0
D PkgDataHelper: notifyAppCreate(), pkgName: com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent, sendRet: true
D MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent, userId = 0
D PkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent
I GameSDK@LifeCycle: noteResumeComponent(): package name  : com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent
D PkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent
I [SmartSwitchAgent]DialogActivity: onCreate : action - com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent.action.START_FROM_SETTINGS
I [SmartSwitchAgent]DialogActivity: showDownloadAppDialog - com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent.action.START_FROM_SETTINGS
I GameSDK@LifeCycle: noteResumeComponent(): package name  : com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent
D PkgPredictorService: pkg:com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent activity:com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent.DialogActivity thisTime:125
D ArtManagerInternalImpl: /data/misc/iorapd/com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent/170000040/com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent.DialogActivity/compiled_traces/compiled_trace.pb doesn't exist
I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent/.DialogActivity: +125ms
D MdnieScenarioControlService:  packageName : com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent    className : com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent.DialogActivity
E BufferQueueProducer: [com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent/com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent.DialogActivity$_29981#0](id:103400000187,api:0,p:-1,c:4148) disconnect: not connected (req=1)
I PackageManager:           pkg{com.sec.android.easyMover}
I PackageManager:           Request from{com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent}
I Finsky  : [2] angy.b(75): VerifyApps: Install-time verification requested for package com.sec.android.easyMover, id = 9
I GOS:GameServiceReceiver:  PkgInstallStarted for com.sec.android.easyMover UserID : 0
I Finsky  : [522] VerifyAppsInstallTask.mu(57): VerifyApps: Anti-malware verification task started for package=com.sec.android.easyMover
I Finsky  : [522] akfb.d(214): TU:tosToken is empty
I Finsky  : [522] annt.a(66): Single user settings service is not running, bind it now
I Finsky  : [2] ttk.onServiceConnected(87): Single user settings service is connected
I GOS:GameIntentService: onHandleIntent(). extras: Bundle[{changeType=2, userId=0, type=15, packageName=com.sec.android.easyMover}]
I GOS:GameIntentService: onHandleIntent(). changeType(INSTALL_STARTED), packageName(com.sec.android.easyMover), UserHandle(0), userId(0), Installed(false)
W GOS:PackageUtil: isVrApp(). PackageManager.NameNotFoundException: com.sec.android.easyMover
I GOS:SystemEventReactor: addPkgDataFromServer(), A package was added : com.sec.android.easyMover as non-game
I Finsky  : [522] VerifyAppsInstallTask.Z(228): VerifyApps: Install is on enterprise device
I Finsky  : [522] akfb.d(214): TU:tosToken is empty
I Finsky  : [522] VerifyAppsInstallTask.ai(201): VerifyApps: Installer app: com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent
I Finsky  : [522] akfb.d(214): TU:tosToken is empty
I Finsky  : [522] rwh.e(31): Task 7 requested foreground
I Finsky  : [522] rwh.e(90): Not entering foreground
I Finsky  : [177] anlg.a(73): VerifyApps: Starting APK Analysis scan for com.sec.android.easyMover.
I Finsky  : [177] aneq.b(187): Scanning package com.sec.android.easyMover contents with client side protections. File: [TZmS8EWUTto7Z18wNtPfVaZA0pMvQiQND6qE-w-hYxU]
I Finsky  : [177] anlg.a(243): VerifyApps: APK Analysis scan finished for com.sec.android.easyMover. Verdict: SAFE
I Finsky  : [530] anmp.g(71): VerifyApps: Verification package=com.sec.android.easyMover, id=9, response=0, upload_requested=false
I Finsky  : [522] VerifyRequiredSplitTypesInstallTask.mu(55): VerifyApps: Starting required split types check for com.sec.android.easyMover.
I Finsky  : [522] VerifyRequiredSplitTypesInstallTask.mu(630): VerifyApps: Required split types check successful for com.sec.android.easyMover.
I Finsky  : [522] VerifyAdvancedProtectionInstallTask.mu(11): VerifyApps AdvancedProtection: Verify AP install started
I Finsky  : [522] VerifyAdvancedProtectionInstallTask.mu(44): VerifyApps AdvancedProtection: Allowing install because there are no Advanced Protection users
I Finsky  : [2] VerifyAdvancedProtectionInstallTask.ms(33): VerifyApps AdvancedProtection: Reported Advanced Protection verification result: ALLOW
I Finsky  : [522] VerifyPerSourceInstallationConsentInstallTask.mu(343): Skipping logging for attempted installation. The source is a system package.
I Finsky  : [522] akfb.d(214): TU:tosToken is empty
I Finsky  : [522] VerifyInstallTask.j(25): VerifyApps: Returning package verification result id=9, result=ALLOW
I Finsky  : [2] VerifyInstallTask.ms(82): VerifyApps: Install-time verification complete: id=9, package_name=com.sec.android.easyMover
I Finsky  : [177] akfb.d(214): TU:tosToken is empty
I Finsky  : [164] akfb.d(214): TU:tosToken is empty
I AASA_ASKSManager:  advanced hash::0c7f814f2dd994ce55e16dd062472d14a57ade935f12cb075e349e526ee13ff2
I AASA_ASKSManager:  AASA_VerifyToken START
I AASA_ASKSManager: index : 1.1
D AASA_ASKSManager: mTokenName : SEC-INF/buildinfo.xml SignerVersion : 
I AASA_ASKSManager: signerCert is verificated!
I AASA_ASKSManager: CAcert is verificated!
I AASA_ASKSManager: rootCert is verificated!
I AASA_ASKSManager: OK:com.sec.android.easyMover
I AASA_ASKSManager: OK:HASH
I AASA_ASKSManager: OK:CROSSDOWN
D AASA_ASKSManager: CREATE : 20240927
I AASA_ASKSManager:  Pass ALL
I AASA_ASKSManager: AASA OK
E AASA_ASKSManager_ADP: file does not exist - /data/system/.aasa/AASApolicy/ADP.xml
I AASA_ASKSManager:  com.sec.android.easyMover is installing..
V LocationManagerService: location appop changed for com.sec.android.easyMover
I MediaProvider: Invalidating LocalCallingIdentity cache for package com.sec.android.easyMover. Reason: op android:read_external_storage
D AASA_ASKSManager_RESTRICTED: There is no restricted rule.
V installd: DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/~~SF8l2NqbjTgHNBJXOAAzaA==/com.sec.android.easyMover-y_zG82YbMS_FwpQC9o25gQ==/base.apk' ---
V installd: DexInv: --- END '/data/app/~~SF8l2NqbjTgHNBJXOAAzaA==/com.sec.android.easyMover-y_zG82YbMS_FwpQC9o25gQ==/base.apk' (success) ---
D ActivityManager: Received BROADCAST intent 0x3782dd Key{broadcastIntent pkg=com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent intent=act=com.sec.android.easyMover.Agent.action.INSTALLER_CALLBACK flags=0x0 u=0} requestCode=2094523420 sent=0 from uid 1000
D MultiUserInstallPolicy: applyInstallPolicyPackageInternalLPw : com.sec.android.easyMover
D MultiUserInstallPolicy: installedOrEnabledPackage : com.sec.android.easyMover
I MediaProvider: Invalidating LocalCallingIdentity cache for package com.sec.android.easyMover. Reason: package android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
D OverlayManager: updateAssets -> not for themes [com.sec.android.easyMover] avoidRelaunch false
D RegisteredServicesCache: com.sec.android.easyMover is not related HCE package
D PkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.sec.android.easyMover
D PkgPredictorService-MultiUserPkgManager: user=0  uid=10253 onPackageStatusChange com.sec.android.easyMover action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
I DomainFilter: onReceive() - Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
I DomainFilter: packageAdded() - packageName: com.sec.android.easyMover, uid: 0
D PkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.sec.android.easyMover
D FaceWidgetMetadataParser: updatePackage() com.sec.android.easyMover true
I PackageInfoManager_FLP: action : ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED, packageName = com.sec.android.easyMover
I Finsky  : [2] aaae.i(1): aaae - Received: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED, [A8r-ZbYHTkoJ-HfsNlPT8P0or96hBfT7EGXtJXSAC80]
D FaceWidgetMetadataParser: removePackage() key = com.sec.android.easyMover
I Finsky:background: [2] zzu.i(6): zzu - Received: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED, [A8r-ZbYHTkoJ-HfsNlPT8P0or96hBfT7EGXtJXSAC80]
I PackageInfoManager_FLP: handled onPackageAdded for com.sec.android.easyMover(DENY)
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstalledReceiver
I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.INFO] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.sec.android.easyMover cmp=com.sec.android.easyMover/.ui.launch.LaunchIntentActivity (has extras)} from uid 10149
D DexPreloader: create a new DexPreloadTask pkg:com.sec.android.easyMover  path:/data/app/~~SF8l2NqbjTgHNBJXOAAzaA==/com.sec.android.easyMover-y_zG82YbMS_FwpQC9o25gQ==
I Finsky:background: [2029] pso.accept(69): Wrote row to frosting DB: 1422
I Finsky  : [150] wln.v(77): # besf@a9f1c025 not available [restriction=9].
I Finsky  : [149] wln.v(77): # besf@a9f1c025 not available [restriction=9].
I Finsky  : [147] vzm.d(89): Item is not available. Reason: 6
D DexPreloader: /data/app/~~SF8l2NqbjTgHNBJXOAAzaA==/com.sec.android.easyMover-y_zG82YbMS_FwpQC9o25gQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex is already preloaded
D MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.sec.android.easyMover, userId = 0
I Finsky  : [150] amlt.aF(98): com.sec.android.easyMover not available availableViaToc=true availabilityStatus=6
I Finsky  : [149] amlt.aF(98): com.sec.android.easyMover not available availableViaToc=true availabilityStatus=6
I Finsky  : [2] aoan.c(44): Do not start WearSupportService due to Wear service optimization
I VvmPkgInstalledRcvr: onReceive() : action android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED packageName :com.sec.android.easyMover
I Finsky  : [2] lxd.f(9): AIM: AppInfoCacheUpdater -> invalidating apps: [com.sec.android.easyMover]
I Finsky  : [2] lxq.c(21): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > getApps > called for 1 apps
I Finsky  : [160] lyy.a(58): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > OnDeviceAppInfo > cacheHitCount=0, cacheMissCount=1. Missed  in cache (limit 10) : [com.sec.android.easyMover]
I Finsky  : [160] leq.apply(1124): AIM: Got app ownership map. App counts: . Unique apps: 0
E Finsky  : [160] nuf.c(20): [Counters] attempted to use a non-positive increment for: 4752
I GOS:GameIntentService: onHandleIntent(). extras: Bundle[{changeType=0, userId=0, type=15, packageName=com.sec.android.easyMover}]
I GOS:GameIntentService: onHandleIntent(). changeType(INSTALLED), packageName(com.sec.android.easyMover), UserHandle(0), userId(0), Installed(true)
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.packagemonitor.impl.PackageMonitorReceiverImpl$RegisteredReceiver
D StorageManagerService: getExternalStorageMountMode: uid=10253 packageName=com.sec.android.easyMover
I Finsky:background: [2029] pso.accept(69): Wrote row to frosting DB: 1423
E Finsky  : [160] nuf.c(20): [Counters] attempted to use a non-positive increment for: 4753
I Telecom:SamsungCommonPolicyPackageBroadcastReceiver: action : android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED / packageName : com.sec.android.easyMover
I Finsky  : [160] lyy.a(58): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > OnDeviceAppInfo > cacheHitCount=0, cacheMissCount=1. Missed  in cache (limit 10) : [com.sec.android.easyMover]
D ImsResolver: maybeAddedImsService, packageName: com.sec.android.easyMover
I Finsky  : [160] leq.apply(1124): AIM: Got app ownership map. App counts: . Unique apps: 0
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.packagemonitor.backgroundimpl.BackgroundPackageMonitorReceiverImpl$RegisteredReceiver
E Finsky  : [160] nuf.c(20): [Counters] attempted to use a non-positive increment for: 4752
I ActivityManager: Start proc 3549:com.sec.android.easyMover/u0a253 for pre-top-activity {com.sec.android.easyMover/com.sec.android.easyMover.ui.launch.LaunchIntentActivity}
I Finsky  : [2] agew.f(9): Clearing split related stale data.
I Finsky  : [148] wln.v(77): # besf@a9f1c025 not available [restriction=9].
I Finsky  : [147] vzm.d(89): Item is not available. Reason: 6
I Finsky  : [2] ufo.jH(13): DTU: Received onPackageAdded, replacing: false
I Finsky  : [150] wln.v(77): # besf@a9f1c025 not available [restriction=9].
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
I Finsky  : [148] amlt.aF(98): com.sec.android.easyMover not available availableViaToc=true availabilityStatus=6
I Finsky  : [150] amlt.aF(98): com.sec.android.easyMover not available availableViaToc=true availabilityStatus=6
I Finsky  : [2] laa.kp(693): Updated the AppUsageStatsCache
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.games.chimera.GamesSystemBroadcastReceiverProxy
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.gass.chimera.PackageChangeBroadcastReceiver
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.samsung.android.app.taskedge/.edgepanel.TaskEdgePanelProvider
I ActivityManager: DSS OFF for com.sec.android.easyMover
D ActivityManager: attachApplicationLocked() app=ProcessRecord{69e3353 3549:com.sec.android.easyMover/u0a253} app.isolatedEntryPoint=null instr2=null
E Finsky  : [160] nuf.c(20): [Counters] attempted to use a non-positive increment for: 4753
D PkgDataHelper: notifyAppCreate(), pkgName: com.sec.android.easyMover, sendRet: true
D MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.sec.android.easyMover, userId = 0
V ActivityManager: Changed top to 10253,ProcessRecord{69e3353 3549:com.sec.android.easyMover/u0a253}
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.samsung.android.localeoverlaymanager/.PackageAddedReceiver
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.samsung.android.sm.devicesecurity/.PackageReceiver
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.sec.android.app.soundalive/.SAControlPanelReceiver
W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } to com.sec.imsservice/com.sec.internal.ims.imsservice.ImsIntentReceiver
D PkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.sec.android.easyMover
I GameSDK@LifeCycle: noteResumeComponent(): package name  : com.sec.android.easyMover
D PkgDataHelper: getGamePkgData(). com.sec.android.easyMover
D LauncherAppsService: Callback onPackageAdded: com.sec.android.easyMover, userId: 0, listener: android
D LauncherAppsService: Callback onPackageAdded: com.sec.android.easyMover, userId: 0, listener: com.android.systemui
D LauncherAppsService: Callback onPackageAdded: com.sec.android.easyMover, userId: 0, listener: com.google.android.as
D LauncherAppsService: Callback onPackageAdded: com.sec.android.easyMover, userId: 0, listener: com.sec.android.app.launcher
I PackageUpdatedTask: mAllAppsList.addPackage com.sec.android.easyMover
I Finsky  : [177] lyt.a(229): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > ItemModel > CacheSize=21, cacheHitCount=0, cacheMissCount=0, total appsWithNoServerDataCount=21. Missed  in cache (limit 10) : []
I MSDG[SmartSwitch]FileUtil: makeNomedia path[/data/user/0/com.sec.android.easyMover/files/SmartSwitchLog], res[true]
I MSDG[SmartSwitch]LogCollector: getLogFile : /data/user/0/com.sec.android.easyMover/files/SmartSwitchLog/LastLogSmartSwitchLog_SM-M307FN_2024-10-21_15_10_0.log
I MSDG[SmartSwitch]LogCollector: getLogFile : /data/user/0/com.sec.android.easyMover/files/SmartSwitchLog/PrevLogSmartSwitchLog_SM-M307FN_2024-10-21_15_10_0.log
I MSDG[SmartSwitch]LogCollector: getLogFile : /data/user/0/com.sec.android.easyMover/files/SmartSwitchLog/SmartSwitchLog_SM-M307FN_2024-10-21_15_10_0.zip
I Finsky  : [177] lyt.a(229): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > ItemModel > CacheSize=21, cacheHitCount=0, cacheMissCount=0, total appsWithNoServerDataCount=21. Missed  in cache (limit 10) : []
I Finsky  : [175] kyb.accept(122): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > getApps > data collection finished
I Finsky  : [175] len.run(577): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > maybeDestroyAppInfoManager is called. actives = 0
D DexPreloader: com.sec.android.easyMover pid:3549 dex profile begin
D SehCodecSolutionService: Update top [com.sec.android.easyMover]
I Finsky  : [175] qmo.accept(59): SCH: Scheduling phonesky job Id: 12-1, CT: 1729516243016, Constraints: [{ L: 15000, D: 86400000, C: CHARGING_NONE, I: IDLE_NONE, N: NET_ANY }]
I Finsky  : [175] mbu.apply(170): SCH: Scheduling 1 system job(s)
I Finsky  : [175] aetu.b(261): SCH: Scheduling system job Id: 9024, L: 14608, D: 47595705, C: false, I: false, N: 1
I AppIconSolution: getThemeIconWithBG called with public API, pkg = com.sec.android.easyMover
I AppIconSolution: return adaptive icon for com.sec.android.easyMover
D MetaDataCollector: onReceive: done pkgName=com.sec.android.easyMover
I clouddpc: [PackageChangeHandlerImpl.kt:handleActionForPackage:285] Handling action: [android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED] for package: [com.sec.android.easyMover]
I clouddpc: [PackageChangeHandlerImpl.kt:handlePackageInstalled:340] Package com.sec.android.easyMover was not requested for Play install or side loading
I LauncherActivityInfo: packageName: com.sec.android.easyMover, useThemeIcon: false, height: 288, width: 288, density: 640
W GCM     : Unexpected forwarded intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.PersistentIntentOperationService (has extras) }
W NetworkScheduler: Unexpected forwarded intent: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.sec.android.easyMover flg=0x4000010 pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.chimera.PersistentIntentOperationService (has extras) }
D MdnieScenarioControlService:  packageName : com.sec.android.easyMover    className : com.sec.android.easyMover.ui.launch.LaunchIntentActivity
I MSDG[SmartSwitch]LauncherActivity: onCreate, taskId : 333, intent : Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.INFO] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.sec.android.easyMover cmp=com.sec.android.easyMover/.ui.launch.LaunchIntentActivity (has extras) }
I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.sec.android.easyMover/.ui.launch.DistributionActivity} from uid 10253
I PackageUpdatedTask: added, appInfo : AppInfo(id=94 type=APP hidden=0 container=all_apps screen=-1 rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Smart Switch componentName=ComponentInfo{com.sec.android.easyMover/com.sec.android.easyMover.ui.launch.LauncherActivity} screenType=0)
I PackageInfoManager_FLP: updatePermission, com.sec.android.easyMover to DENY
D MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.sec.android.easyMover, userId = 0
D PkgDataHelper: notifyAppCreate(), pkgName: com.sec.android.easyMover, sendRet: true
D MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.sec.android.easyMover, userId = 0
I MSDG[SmartSwitch]DistributionActivity: onCreate, taskId : 333, intent : Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.sec.android.easyMover/.ui.launch.DistributionActivity }
I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {flg=0x10008000 cmp=com.sec.android.easyMover/.ui.WelcomeActivity (has extras)} from uid 10253
W ActivityTaskManager: Duplicate finish request for r=ActivityRecord{570d64f u0 com.sec.android.easyMover/.ui.launch.DistributionActivity t333 f}}
D MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.sec.android.easyMover, userId = 0
I FILP/PackageIntentReceiver: pkgName : com.sec.android.easyMover
D PkgDataHelper: notifyAppCreate(), pkgName: com.sec.android.easyMover, sendRet: true
D MARsPolicyManager: onPackageResumedFG pkgName = com.sec.android.easyMover, userId = 0
I Finsky  : [160] akfb.d(214): TU:tosToken is empty
I GameLauncherManagerImp: com.sec.android.easyMover does not contain game list
I Finsky  : [177] akfb.d(214): TU:tosToken is empty
I GameSDK@LifeCycle: noteResumeComponent(): package name  : com.sec.android.easyMover
I Finsky  : [157] nyj.kp(172): [ContentSync] finished, scheduled=true
I PackageInfoManager_FLP: updatePermission, com.sec.android.easyMover to DENY
D PkgPredictorService: pkg:com.sec.android.easyMover activity:com.sec.android.easyMover.ui.WelcomeActivity thisTime:1051
D ArtManagerInternalImpl: /data/misc/iorapd/com.sec.android.easyMover/376001130/com.sec.android.easyMover.ui.WelcomeActivity/compiled_traces/compiled_trace.pb doesn't exist
I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.sec.android.easyMover/.ui.WelcomeActivity: +1s51ms
D RegisteredServicesCache: com.sec.android.easyMover is not related HCE package
D FaceWidgetMetadataParser: updatePackage() com.sec.android.easyMover false
D FaceWidgetMetadataParser: removePackage() key = com.sec.android.easyMover
I DWBLocalPackageManager: onPackageAdded Already Exist : com.sec.android.easyMover
I Finsky  : [2] aaae.i(1): aaae - Received: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED, [A8r-ZbYHTkoJ-HfsNlPT8P0or96hBfT7EGXtJXSAC80]
I Finsky  : [2] lxd.f(9): AIM: AppInfoCacheUpdater -> invalidating apps: [com.sec.android.easyMover]
I Finsky  : [2] lxq.c(21): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > getApps > called for 1 apps
I Finsky  : [160] lyy.a(58): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > OnDeviceAppInfo > cacheHitCount=0, cacheMissCount=1. Missed  in cache (limit 10) : [com.sec.android.easyMover]
I Finsky  : [147] wln.v(77): # besf@a9f1c025 not available [restriction=9].
I Finsky  : [150] wln.v(77): # besf@a9f1c025 not available [restriction=9].
I Finsky  : [164] leq.apply(1124): AIM: Got app ownership map. App counts: . Unique apps: 0
E Finsky  : [164] nuf.c(20): [Counters] attempted to use a non-positive increment for: 4752
I Finsky  : [147] amlt.aF(98): com.sec.android.easyMover not available availableViaToc=true availabilityStatus=6
I Finsky  : [150] amlt.aF(98): com.sec.android.easyMover not available availableViaToc=true availabilityStatus=6
E Finsky  : [160] nuf.c(20): [Counters] attempted to use a non-positive increment for: 4753
I Finsky  : [149] vzm.d(89): Item is not available. Reason: 6
I Finsky  : [175] lyy.a(58): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > OnDeviceAppInfo > cacheHitCount=1, cacheMissCount=0. Missed  in cache (limit 10) : []
I Finsky  : [175] leq.apply(1124): AIM: Got app ownership map. App counts: . Unique apps: 0
E Finsky  : [175] nuf.c(20): [Counters] attempted to use a non-positive increment for: 4752
E Finsky  : [175] nuf.c(20): [Counters] attempted to use a non-positive increment for: 4753
D ImsResolver: maybeAddedImsService, packageName: com.sec.android.easyMover
I Finsky:background: [2] zzu.i(6): zzu - Received: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED, [A8r-ZbYHTkoJ-HfsNlPT8P0or96hBfT7EGXtJXSAC80]
I Finsky  : [147] wln.v(77): # besf@a9f1c025 not available [restriction=9].
I Finsky  : [147] amlt.aF(98): com.sec.android.easyMover not available availableViaToc=true availabilityStatus=6
I Finsky  : [147] wln.v(77): # besf@a9f1c025 not available [restriction=9].
I Finsky  : [148] vzm.d(89): Item is not available. Reason: 6
I Finsky  : [147] amlt.aF(98): com.sec.android.easyMover not available availableViaToc=true availabilityStatus=6
I clouddpc: [PackageChangeHandlerImpl.kt:handleActionForPackage:285] Handling action: [android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED] for package: [com.sec.android.easyMover]
I Finsky  : [175] lyt.a(229): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > ItemModel > CacheSize=21, cacheHitCount=0, cacheMissCount=0, total appsWithNoServerDataCount=21. Missed  in cache (limit 10) : []
I Finsky:background: [2029] pso.accept(69): Wrote row to frosting DB: 1424
I Finsky:background: [2029] pso.accept(69): Wrote row to frosting DB: 1425
I Finsky  : [175] lyt.a(229): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > ItemModel > CacheSize=21, cacheHitCount=0, cacheMissCount=0, total appsWithNoServerDataCount=21. Missed  in cache (limit 10) : []
I Finsky  : [175] kyb.accept(122): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > getApps > data collection finished
I Finsky  : [175] len.run(577): AIM: AppInfoManager-Perf > maybeDestroyAppInfoManager is called. actives = 0
I GOS:GameServiceReceiver:  Package changeType : ENABLED, packageName : com.sec.android.easyMover
I PackageUpdatedTask: mAllAppsList.updatePackage com.sec.android.easyMover
D SehCodecSolutionService: Update top [com.sec.android.easyMover]
I AppIconSolution: getThemeIconWithBG called with public API, pkg = com.sec.android.easyMover
I AppIconSolution: return adaptive icon for com.sec.android.easyMover
I LauncherActivityInfo: packageName: com.sec.android.easyMover, useThemeIcon: false, height: 288, width: 288, density: 640
I PackageUpdatedTask: modified, appInfo : AppInfo(id=94 type=APP hidden=0 container=all_apps screen=0 rank=19 user=UserHandle{0} title=Smart Switch componentName=ComponentInfo{com.sec.android.easyMover/com.sec.android.easyMover.ui.launch.LauncherActivity} screenType=0)
I GOS:GameIntentService: onHandleIntent(). extras: Bundle[{changeType=4, type=15, packageName=com.sec.android.easyMover}]
I GOS:GameIntentService: onHandleIntent(). changeType(ENABLED), packageName(com.sec.android.easyMover), UserHandle(0), userId(0), Installed(true)
D MdnieScenarioControlService:  packageName : com.sec.android.easyMover    className : com.sec.android.easyMover.ui.WelcomeActivity


